# When to use Lightning Event

Tags: lightning

Can someone explain to me when should I use Lightning event when creating Lightning Components?

And kindly give an example thanks.

Kinda confused with the documentation that I'm reading for example Lightning Event in trailhead.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what part of the Trailhead do you not understand, can you link the part that confuses you? so someone can help clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of events: Application Events and Component Events.

Application events should be used sparingly because they go to all components and (even if only a few components actually handle the event) that can slow things down. An example where I have used them is in a customer community where each page was to be viewed in the context of a particular Account. I put an Account switcher component in the header part of the page, then fired an Application event when the Account changed. This allowed all components on the page to change context and show information specific to that Account.

Component events are for a child component to communicate with its parent (that is, the child is contained inside the parent). An example of this is found in the standard components themselves e.g.  ui:menuList fires a ui:menuSelect event when the menu is clicked. If you put a ui:menuList in your custom component, you can handle that event coming up from the child, and take some appropriate action.

The other inter-component communication mechanism is via attributes. A parent can communicate with its children by changing the values of their attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, Events are used to establish communication between components.
If you want to send the data from one component to another component, we use events.

You fire an event in the source component and this event will be handled by any other component depends on the type.

Let's take an example of Account Search.
In this scenario, you need to have an input field to enter the search string and you need to display the result in a table.

Component 1: create a input field and a button to perform a search. Call the apex and get the data.
Component 2: Display the result in a table.

You will get the list of records after clicking on a search button and you need to pass these records to component 2 to display. Here we use Events.

2 types events:
Application Events and Component Events

Application Events are used to establish communication between two or more independent components.

Component Events are used to establish communication between the components which are in containment hierarchy.

Note: Ofcourse, you can do this use case in a single component. I just took this as an example to explain the events.

Hope it helps.